# How is the compiler selected including flags while running python setup.py

Tags: python, c++, windows, compiler-flags

I have difficulties understanding how the compiler and its flags is selected when I want to compile a python package with some c++ extensions. I run it with `py setup.py build_ext --inplace --force` on my Windows machine. I get different compiler depending on if I run the script from PowerShell or from `x86 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2017`.
With PowerShell:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe
> /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -IC ...

With x86 Native Tool for VS 2017:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe
> /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -IC ...

In both cases was the flag `/MT` used I want to compile the code with `/MD`.

This is how the `setup.py` looks:

```
import setuptools
from numpy.distutils.core import setup
from numpy.distutils.misc_util import Configuration
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy
import os.path
import sys

config = Configuration()

utils_dir = "project_name/systems/cppsystems/utils"
utils_files = os.listdir(utils_dir)
utils_files = [x.lower() for x in utils_files]
utils_files = filter(lambda x: x.endswith("cpp") or x.endswith("c"), utils_files)
utils_files = [os.path.join(utils_dir, x) for x in utils_files]
config.add_include_dirs([utils_dir,])
config.add_library("utils",utils_files)

extensions = [ Extension("project_name.systems.cppsystems.part1",
                          list_of_files,
                          language="c++",
                          include_dirs=some_dirs,
                          library_dirs=some_other_dirs,
                          libraries= some_libs+['utils'],
                          ),
                Extension("project_name.systems.cppsystems.part2",
                          list_of_files2,
                          language="c++",
                          include_dirs=some_dirs2,
                          library_dirs=some_other_dirs2,
                          libraries= some_libs2+['utils'],
                          )
              ]
setup(
    name="project_name",
    version="1.0.0",
    ext_modules=cythonize(extensions),
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    install_requires = required,
    **config.todict()
    
)
```

For the extensions I could add an `extra_compile_args = ["-MD"]` and then I get a warning like this:

> cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/MT' with '/MD'

But I couldn't figure out how to set this for my utils package. However setting this extra arguments for each package seems like the wrong path to go, I prefer to use the correct from the beginning. Any suggestions?

Comment: The compile flags seem to be [hard coded to use `/MD`](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/a4dbe3457d89cf67ee3aa571fdb149e6eb544e88/setuptools/_distutils/_msvccompiler.py#L250) are you using a recent version of setuptools? This was [changed](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/commit/d8d513d728552adee0677d5814eecc06d7775749) a year ago

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much for pointing me here :) I had an updated version of setuptools in my venv but an old in my "global Python" installation where distutils are located.